# What is the purpose of the following function in this code block?

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

I can't seem to figure out what the actual importance is for including the following block of code in an exercise in Chapter 6 of *Eloquent Javascript*.

**Edit: It's not needed but rather there to allow for calling it from the top level.**

```
function countZeroes(array) {
  return count(equals(0), array);
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
function count(test, array) {
  return reduce(function(total, element) {
    return total + (test(element) ? 1 : 0);
  }, 0, array);
}

function equals(x) {
  return function(element) {return x === element;};
}

function countZeroes(array) {
  return count(equals(0), array);
}
```

Here is the reduce function from earlier:

```
function reduce(combine, base, array) {
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
  });
  return base;
}
```

Here is the forEach function from earlier:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
```

I've only just begun learning JavaScript so I'm sure there is a simple explanation for this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking what the point of the `countZeroes` function is?  If you never *call* it, then you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is never called...

Most probably the intention is to be able to call it from the top level. Instead of:

```
show(count(equals(0), [2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3]));
```

you could have

```
var a = [1,4,5,0];
show( countZeroes( a ) );
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I knew I was overlooking something painfully simple as to why the author would have bothered to include it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function `countZeros` never called.

I think the native function [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is better/faster.

```
function count (whatToCount, theArrayToCount) {
    return theArrayToCount.filter (function (element) {
        // If they are same, keep; Otherwise remove from array
        return element === whatToCount;
    }).length; // Count the "filtered" Array, and return it.
}

count (0, [2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3]); // 3
```

btw, the callbacks are confusing (..